# See Real Time Calculations in Excel?

Tags: excel

Is there a way to see (in something like a Terminal or Command Prompt window for example) exactly what Excel is processing? I guess I can equate this to Verbose startup mode for OS X. My goal here is to see if Excel is actually doing calculations, or just hanging.

Comment: Apologies if you are aware, but Excel usually writes `Calculating` in the status bar if it is taking a while. But I expect you want more than this.

Answer (score 0):

you can see excels "process" by clicking on formulas and then "evaluate formula"

which shows the step by step procedure it takes.